# bash "-e" puzzler: script file ended unexpectedly

Tags: bash, shell

To make things clear, I would short my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e  

p_time=$(expr 0 - 0)
echo ?
echo "process time(sec) is: " ${p_time}
```

The file would end before "echo ?", but if I change "p_time=$(expr 0 - 0)" to "p_time=$(expr 3 - 0)", the file would end correctly.
However, if I removed "-e" in the first sentence, the file ended correctly too.
Why would this happen?

Comment: This is one reason why many people recommend not using the `-e` option; a non-zero exit code doesn't always indicate an *error*.

Comment: If you have any questions about just how sane and predictable the behavior of `set -e` is, consider going through the exercises in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), or reviewing the table demonstrating incompatibilities between different shells' implementations at https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/

Comment: BTW, as an aside, `expr` is a relic of the 1970s and shouldn't be used in modern scripts. `p_time=$((0 - 0))` is guaranteed to work with every shell compliant with the 1991 POSIX.2 standard, and is *far* more efficient (as it avoids `fork()`ing off a subprocess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash -e` means `Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.`

The result of `0 - 0` is `0`, so the exit code of `expr 0 - 0` is `1` and Bash will exit immediately. If you remove `-e`, Bash will ignore the exit code of `expr 0 - 0` and will execute all commands in your script.